# Rebol select like function returning more than just the next value?

Tags: rebol

Does this exist ? If not what's the best way to create it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use find/tail,

```
>> find/tail [a b c d e] 'c
== [d e]
>> find/tail [a b c d e] 'x
== none
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution....I should try reading the docs first in future :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return **all** the values after the target value, you can use **next find**

eg:

```
data: copy [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
select data 5
== 6            ;; returns the next value only.
find data 5
== [5 6 7 8 9]  ;; returns the series at that point, so ...
next find data 5
== [6 7 8 9]    ;; ... returns the series after that point.
```

If you just want the next N items, add a **copy/part...N**

eg (next three items):

```
copy/part next find data 5 3
== [6 7 8]
```

I'll leave you to add the error code for when the value is not found:

```
next find data 0
```